# Incremental loading for fact table in informatica

Tags: informatica

I am performing SCD type 1 mapping. I have these source tables.

```
1.CUSTOMERS, (Source customer File)
2.PRODUCTS (Source Product File)
3.SALES   (source Sales file)
```

Also, these are dimensions and fact tables.

```
1.D_CUSTOMERS (SCD 1),
2.D_PRODUCTS (SCD 1) and
3.F_SALES_DLY (Fact)
```

Sales contains daily level data. Fact table will have sales & quantity data aggregated for product & for a month.(Fact table should be incremental for 24 months.(It should always contain 24 months of data)

I am bit confused, How to make fact table incremental? If i try to use any transformation(filter) to get last 24 months records, is it feasible solution?

Please suggest me something..

Thanks...

Comment: One way to implement it is split the task into two steps: (1) create a mapping that will delete transactions older than 24 months, (2) create a second mapping to get the transactions for the last 24 months from `SALES`, aggregate it and then insert the new values and update the existing ones. However, that's pretty obvious, so I think I don't understand your question entirely. What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: @Marek Grzenkowicz: Thank you so much for your reply. I need only 24 months data in my fact table. Data should be deleted or added over time. You suggested me the same thing which i was thinking about. I am doing this just for practice. Can you please tell me, what is use of incremental aggregation tab in session properties? Will that option help to solve this?

Comment: This feature affects the performance of the session but not the results. More information: http://www.dwbiconcepts.com/etl/14-etl-informatica/20-implementing-informaticas-incremental-aggregation.html and http://informaticatutorials-naveen.blogspot.com/2011/04/incremental-aggregation_20.html

Comment: @Marek Grzenkowicz: Thank you..